# How do I implement the MIC correlation algorithm in python?

Tags: python, correlation

The [algorithm](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep06662) for finding correlation in non-linear data has some python resources, namely [minepy](https://github.com/minepy) and its tool for MIC analysis [mictools](https://pypi.org/project/mictools/). However, it all seems very obscure and it's unclear how I could use it in a python program to find the MIC correlation between two lists x and y.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I have checked the documentation for the minepy API, however it's a bit unclear what the 'alpha' and 'c' parameters in minepy.MINE represent.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on GitHub is terrible, however it does contain the one useful thing: the pointer to the [paper by Reshef et al.](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume17/15-308/15-308.pdf), which gives a fair bit of background and explanation (no, it is not a model of lucidity either, but much better than the alternatives).